# unable to install package using PIP for python

Tags: python, package, installation, pip

I am having issues installing any package on mac os. I have tried updating pip , installed python. uninstalled python and bunch of other stuff that I have tried.

Ran the command **pip3 install indicoio**

error as below kindly share your thoughts on how I can overcome this error

```
Collecting indicoio
  Using cached IndicoIo-1.0.4.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    warning: no files found matching '*.sh'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_static'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.coveragerc'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.editorconfig'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.landscape.yaml'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'appveyor.yml'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'build_children.sh'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'tox.ini'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '.git*' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 156, in save_modules
        yield saved
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 197, in setup_context
        yield
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 246, in run_setup
        DirectorySandbox(setup_dir).run(runner)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 276, in run
        return func()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 245, in runner
        _execfile(setup_script, ns)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 47, in _execfile
        exec(code, globals, locals)
      File "/tmp/easy_install-mq2t7d4s/Pillow-3.4.2/setup.py", line 753, in <module>
      File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.2_3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.2_3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/distutils/dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.2_3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/command/bdist_egg.py", line 161, in run
        cmd = self.call_command('install_lib', warn_dir=0)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/command/bdist_egg.py", line 147, in call_command
        self.run_command(cmdname)
      File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.2_3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.2_3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/command/install_lib.py", line 11, in run
        self.build()
      File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.2_3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/distutils/command/install_lib.py", line 107, in build
        self.run_command('build_ext')
      File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.2_3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.2_3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.2_3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 338, in run
        self.build_extensions()
      File "/tmp/easy_install-mq2t7d4s/Pillow-3.4.2/setup.py", line 521, in build_extensions
    ValueError: jpeg is required unless explicitly disabled using --disable-jpeg, aborting

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/tmp/pip-build-669f5s37/indicoio/setup.py", line 52, in <module>
        "futures >= 3.0.0"
      File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.2_3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/distutils/core.py", line 108, in setup
        _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 348, in __init__
        self.fetch_build_eggs(attrs['setup_requires'])
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 394, in fetch_build_eggs
        replace_conflicting=True,
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 826, in resolve
        dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(req, ws, installer)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1098, in best_match
        return self.obtain(req, installer)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1110, in obtain
        return installer(requirement)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 461, in fetch_build_egg
        return cmd.easy_install(req)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 664, in easy_install
        return self.install_item(spec, dist.location, tmpdir, deps)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 694, in install_item
        dists = self.install_eggs(spec, download, tmpdir)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 875, in install_eggs
        return self.build_and_install(setup_script, setup_base)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1114, in build_and_install
        self.run_setup(setup_script, setup_base, args)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1100, in run_setup
        run_setup(setup_script, args)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 249, in run_setup
        raise
      File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.2_3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py", line 77, in __exit__
        self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 197, in setup_context
        yield
      File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.2_3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py", line 77, in __exit__
        self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 168, in save_modules
        saved_exc.resume()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 143, in resume
        six.reraise(type, exc, self._tb)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/_vendor/six.py", line 685, in reraise
        raise value.with_traceback(tb)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 156, in save_modules
        yield saved
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 197, in setup_context
        yield
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 246, in run_setup
        DirectorySandbox(setup_dir).run(runner)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 276, in run
        return func()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 245, in runner
        _execfile(setup_script, ns)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 47, in _execfile
        exec(code, globals, locals)
      File "/tmp/easy_install-mq2t7d4s/Pillow-3.4.2/setup.py", line 753, in <module>
      File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.2_3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.2_3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/distutils/dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.2_3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/command/bdist_egg.py", line 161, in run
        cmd = self.call_command('install_lib', warn_dir=0)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/command/bdist_egg.py", line 147, in call_command
        self.run_command(cmdname)
      File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.2_3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.2_3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/command/install_lib.py", line 11, in run
        self.build()
      File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.2_3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/distutils/command/install_lib.py", line 107, in build
        self.run_command('build_ext')
      File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.2_3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.2_3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.2_3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 338, in run
        self.build_extensions()
      File "/tmp/easy_install-mq2t7d4s/Pillow-3.4.2/setup.py", line 521, in build_extensions
    ValueError: jpeg is required unless explicitly disabled using --disable-jpeg, aborting

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-build-669f5s37/indicoio/
```

Comment: When you uninstalled python, did you check if there were any files remaining inside the different directories?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Does_exactly_what_it_says_on_the_tin

Comment: @angelwally not yet. will check that.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
sudo python setup.py install
```

In the directory that you installed the folder. If that doesn't work try

```
python setup.py --help-command
```

Above is the code that showed me the other commands on Windows I am not sure what the equivalent is on Mac. But I found specific installation functions such as install_lib and install_scripts.

Comment: Tried this it did not help

Comment: I wish I could help more but I don't have a Mac :(